# Tkinter label not updating after file changes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been trying to get the Tkinter label update when the content of the file is changed. 
The program reads multiple file and displays the contents in Tkinter Label widgets. Whenever there is change in the contents of file, I need to make label update every X seconds.
Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
'''test.log
test1
test2
test3
'''
file = 'test.log'
# reading test.log file content
def refresh():
    with open(file) as f:
        lines = []
        for line in f:
            lines.append(line)
        print(lines)
    root.after(300, refresh)
    return lines

#file1 =  (read_file1())

root = Tk()
root.geometry('250x400')

# multiple widgets1
file1Label1 = Label(root, text=refresh(), bg="gray", fg="white")
file1Label1.pack(side="top")
# multiple widgets2
#def refresh():
#    file1
#    root.after(1*60*1000, refresh)
refresh()
root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to use `after` method to schedule a function and run every X millisecond and it is not working as expected. Does anyone have better solution how to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: if your `refresh()` function just does a `print("refresh occurred!")` then does it get printed at the frequency you expect? your function just has `file1` on it's own line which isn't going to do anything, is that your actual code?

Comment: Yeah this is the actual code that I am testing

Comment: so what are you expecting `file1` just put on its own line to accomplish?

Comment: If there is change in the content of the file test.log i.e. updated entry “test 4”. I would like to see this entry update in the Tkinter GUI label.

Comment: ok so where is your code to check if the file has changed? or code to change `file1Label["text"]` to update label?  Your question is saying the updating logic with after is wrong but I think the scheduling is correct you just don't have any logic to actually modify the label.

Comment: Hmm I do not have that code. Yes question should be "...not updating after ..". Thanks for the notes. I am testing it changing the file locally and expecting refresh function to take care of the label change when it executes every X seconds.

Comment: You should read the file inside `refresh()` and update `file1Label1` with the content of the file.

Comment: @acw1688 I have updated the code moved the read file inside refresh. Now refresh() is printing the change but Tkinter GUI label is not updating in the widget 1. What is missing here .. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by doing the following:
add an argument called label to your function *refresh()*

add in refresh() this code:

```
label.config(text=lines)
```

change line 15 to this:

```
root.after(300, lambda: refresh(label))
```

i've done some other small chages, then your code will become:

```
from tkinter import *
'''test.log
test1
test2
test3
'''
file = 'test.log'
# reading test.log file content
def refresh(label):
    with open(file) as f:
        lines = []
        for line in f:
            lines.append(line)
        print(lines)
    label.config(text=lines)
    root.after(300, lambda: refresh(label))
    return lines

#file1 =  (read_file1())

root = Tk()
root.geometry('250x400')

# multiple widgets1
file1Label1 = Label(root, bg="gray", fg="white")
file1Label1.pack(side="top")
# multiple widgets2
#def refresh():
#    file1
#    root.after(1*60*1000, refresh)
refresh(file1Label1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: oops, i see that i also have changed line 31...